# Some quotes are HTML entities, some aren't- fixing with PHP

Tags: php, html, plist

I'm pulling text from Wordpress posts that has some escaped quotes like

```
Aunt Maude&#8217;s
```

and some with unescaped unicode quotes, like

```
Legend’s American Grill
```

I need to format the text into a plist to be displayed in an iOS app. htmlentities escapes the ampersands in the first example, like

```
Aunt Maude&amp;#8217;s
```

so I've tried decoding everything, then encoding it, but html_entity_decode has no effect. Also, htmlentities changes the quotes to `&rsquo;` which the plist parser doesn't like.

I don't really know what I'm doing here- any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities)'s last parameter allows you not to re-encode entities that have already been encoded, so

```
htmlentities('...&#8217;...', ENT_COMPAT, <YOUR_CHARSET>, false)
```

should work for you.

Comment: Ouch. I did not R enough of TFM. Thanks.

Comment: might just be my test setup, but this seems to return NULL for `Legend’s American Grill`

Comment: How did you call it? I'd use `htmlentities('Legend’s American Grill', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);`